# If $A$ and $B$ are independent with $P(A) = 1/9, P(B) = 1/4$, then what is $P(A|A\cup B)$?

Tags: probability

> $A$ and $B$ are independent
>   $P(A) = 1/9$, $P(B) = 1/4$
>   How much is $P[A|(A\cup B)]$?

I think it's $1/3$, am I correct?

Comment: Generally, you are expected to provide your work (not just a numerical value) so that others can proofread it. It will help if you learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Can you, for example, show us how you compute $P(A\cup B)$?

Comment: I think P(A∪B) is equal to  P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B)

Comment: It is.  So can you compute it?

Comment: what you mean by compute it? if it means doing the math, $P(A\cup B) = 1/3$

Comment: Exactly.  But $P(A\,|\,A\cup B )=\frac {P(A\cap (A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)}=\frac {P(A)}{P(A\cup B)}$.  So...

Comment: Just the revised answer in your post.  $\frac 13$ is correct.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!!!